# JVM errors when running minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft

This is the output I am getting when I am playing minecraft.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning:
 Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Unrecognized VM option 'CMSIncrementalMode'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 11):

Edit your Java arguments (Profile Settings) for starting the game and get rid of CMSIncrementalMode (-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode). If your using Java 8 you don't really need any arguments. If you have not installed Java Look here...[Install Java 8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html)

[image]

Comment: The answer still applies; remove the argument for the error in your profile settings.

Comment: This answer would be so much better if it showed how to go the Java arguments (Profile Settings).

Comment: On the Minecraft launcher, those settings are greyed out though.

Comment: Nvm, I noticed that I also have check-boxes, but they blend in with the background.

Answer (score 2):

Enter your profile settings and at the bottom make sure *JVM Arguments* is selected, then delete `-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode`. That's what worked for me.