# JDK Crash when attempting to run Minecraft on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, games, jdk, openjdk, minecraft

Trying to install Minecraft on 18.04 and I get the following error.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning:
Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0
 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Unrecognized VM option 'CMSIncrementalMode'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

I edited my profile. I changed the JVM Arguments from

```
-Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
```

to

```
-Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
```

Then Minecraft worked for me.

(I got the Idea from: [JVM errors when running minecraft](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943284/jvm-errors-when-running-minecraft))

Answer (score 3):

Replace openjdk-jre-11 with openjdk-jre-8. Minecraft will not run on newer java versions.

Comment: While this may be the case, the OP did not say that were using Java 8 or higher. Also, Java 11 does not exist yet.

Comment: @ubashu Despite the weird nomenclature the openjdk-11-jdk package exists in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @karel Why is this?

Comment: It was explained to me in a blog that I forgot which blog it was that Ubuntu 18.04 will launch a new openjdk-10-jdk package when it becomes available, so it can't use openjdk-10-jdk as a package name because that package name has already been reserved.

Comment: You can add that as well mod's for minecraft are made using java 8, beside that this answer is right and java jre/jdk 8 can be installed alongside the default java 10.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. It is enough to have the launcher profile use java 8 to start minecraft, starting the launcher with java 10 is no problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

Install MC Installer -

```
sudo snap install mc-installer
```

No need to go through JDK/JVM hassle.

Answer (score 0):

just delete all Unrecognized VM options from the JVM Arguments... worked for me

Comment: This is similar to Boba Fit's answer.

Comment: it is not similar because there might be more unrecognized VM options on further runs

Comment: @Assaf_Halevi, I see. Yet I wonder on the consequences for the stability of the game, of removing these options. Is it not a sign that something else should be changed or updated?

Comment: you worry too much