# No Java command after installing Java 8, removing Java 11, despite no err msgs after installation

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, java, openjdk

I'm having a great deal of trouble installing Java 8 onto Kubuntu 18.04 rather than the default Java 11, and would appreciate any help, as the advice from the usual web sites is not helping.

In my particular case, I'm trying to install Java version 8 to run Minecraft, as it does not seem to run on the more current Java 11 (at least for Linux) [as noted here at [JDK Crash when attempting to run Minecraft on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028595/jdk-crash-when-attempting-to-run-minecraft-on-ubuntu-18-04/1030255#1030255) and here at [[Minecraft won't launch in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037121/minecraft-wont-launch-in-ubuntu-18-04][2]) ]

Try as I might to `sudo apt-get remove openjdk-11-jre` or `sudo apt-get purge openjdk-11-jdk` and other similar commands, every time I type `java -version` it tells me that it's version 11 rather than version 8.

Finally, I followed the advice on how to completely uninstall Java, from [How to completely uninstall Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java)

```bsh
$ dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package}\n' | grep -E -e '^(ia32-)?(sun|oracle)-java' -e '^openjdk-' -e '^icedtea' -e '^(default|gcj)-j(re|dk)' -e '^gcj-(.*)-j(re|dk)' -e '^java-common' | xargs sudo apt-get -y remove
$ sudo apt-get -y autoremove
$ sudo bash -c 'ls -d /home/*/.java' | xargs sudo rm -rf
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/jvm/*
$ for g in ControlPanel java java_vm javaws jcontrol jexec keytool mozilla-javaplugin.so orbd pack200 policytool rmid rmiregistry servertool tnameserv unpack200 appletviewer apt extcheck HtmlConverter idlj jar jarsigner javac javadoc javah javap jconsole jdb jhat jinfo jmap jps jrunscript jsadebugd jstack jstat jstatd native2ascii rmic schemagen serialver wsgen wsimport xjc xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so; do sudo update-alternatives --remove-all $g; done
$ sudo updatedb
$ sudo locate -b '\pack200'
```

Finally, no more Java!  And now to reinstall only Java 8 and not Java 11, so I did

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

(I think the second command was redundant.)

And now I do not have any java command.  Typing "java -version"[Enter] results in an error that there is no such command.  However, "javac" *is* a valid command, so apparently I have a Java compiler installed but not a Java whatever-you-call-the-not-compiler (the "run-time environment"?)  Running programs Java-based programs like Minecraft or the mtgForge results in the program self-terminating after a few seconds.

I tried:

```bsh
$ update-java-alternatives --list
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64`
```

Not sure why version 11 is still there. I couldn't seem to use `update-java-alternatives --set` to make version 8 the default (or ANY default at all).  When I tried

```bsh
update-java-alternatives --set 1081
update-java-alternatives: directory does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/1081
```

So then I checked what was available under

```bsh
$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/ 
.java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo  .java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo  java-8-openjdk-amd64/
```

So I tried:

```bsh
$ update-java-alternatives --set java-8-openjdk-amd64
update-java-alternatives: file does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/.java-8-openjdk-amd64.jinfo
```

That's because the filename is different from the directory name. Filename is `.java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo`

On the other hand, using the confusingly similar command

```bsh
$ update-alternatives --config java
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java
```

But if I say

```bsh
$ update-alternatives --config javac
There is only one alternative in link group javac (providing /usr/bin/javac): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
Nothing to configure.
```

This is where I am stuck.  How do I get it so I can run the `java` command?  I already have the `javac` command.  Which package do I need to install to get the `java` command?  As noted above, I've already installed `openjdk-8-jdk` and `openjdk-8-jre`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first block of code looks fishy to me -- there should have been no reason to go to that level.

You shouldn't need the JDK unless you are doing development

`$ sudo apt-get purge openjdk-8-jdk`

I would go ahead and leave the v11 JRE (you can have as many as you want) and reinstall both:

```
$ sudo apt-get reinstall openjdk-11-jre
$ sudo apt-get reinstall openjdk-8-jre
```

As long as there are no errors you should then be able to `update-alternatives --config java`