# How to run Minecraft 1.18.x in (k)ubuntu 20.04 / java 17 throwing errors

Tags: 20.04, java, minecraft, openjdk

How do I get Minecraft 1.18.x to run? I have openjdk-17 installed and Minecraft 1.16.x runs fine with openjdk-8.

The relevant errors in the console are:

[16:37:00 ERROR]: Game ended with bad state (exit code 1)

Unrecognized VM option 'CMSIncrementalMode'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Hint: solved below

Comment: As far as I remember, they all mention using openjdk, which in my particular case, didn't work and I couldn't figure out why. Instead I tried with Oracle's Java 17 and it worked. If openjdk works for them that's great, it seems they have a different issue than me. How is the difference unclear?

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading this it's because none of these worked for you:

[JVM errors when running minecraft](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943284/jvm-errors-when-running-minecraft)

[Problems updating Java on Ubuntu 20.04 for Minecraft 1.18](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379110/problems-updating-java-on-ubuntu-20-04-for-minecraft-1-18/1379111#1379111)

[How to install Java 18 (JRE) on Ubuntu LTS 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379181/how-to-install-java-18-jre-on-ubuntu-lts-20-04)

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 / kernel 5.13.0-28-generic with openjdk-8 and openjdk-17 installed.

I'm also running Minecraft Launcher v 1.6.93 because I like it.

**Solution:**

1- Remove openjdk-17

```
sudo apt remove openjdk-17-*
```

2- Get Oracle's Java 17

```
wget https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.deb
```

3- Install dependencies first

```
sudo apt install libc6-i386
sudo apt install libc6-x32
```

4- Install Java 17

```
sudo dpkg -i jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.deb
```

5- Open your Minecraft launcher and set the Java Settings: Executable to the correct path. In my install it's:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/java
```

and remove all JVM arguments that give problems.

6- Save your profile and play